# iPhone UIWebView - Open new UIWebView Controller from a hyperlink

Tags: iphone

I have an embedded website that has many links but the webview window is fairly small to allow for a larger image above the list to be zoomed in and out.  I need the webview to respond to hyperlinks into a new controller view with a second embedded UIWebView if at all possible.

Answer (score 13):

The UIWebView has a delegate wich allows you to respond to certain events, e.g. a request to load new content. Just implement the following in your delegate-class

```
-(bool) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    //You might need to set up a interceptLinks-Bool since you don't want to intercept the initial loading of the content
    if (self.interceptLinks) {
        NSURL *url = request.URL;
        //This launches your custom ViewController, replace it with your initialization-code
        [YourBrowserViewController openBrowserWithUrl:url];     
        return NO;
    }
    //No need to intercept the initial request to fill the WebView
    else {
        self.interceptLinks = YES;
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: what does this mean?   [BrowserViewController openBrowserWithUrl:url]; ...this line is not working in my project...any help?

Comment: Phlibbo...I have replaced it with my viewController...still not working when I click any hyperlink :(

Comment: Does your viewcontroller support openBrowserWithUrl? It's no standard method, you have to implement it yourself.