# Clicking a link in UIWebView pushes onto the NavigationView stack

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

Basically, I'd like to know how to intercept a click in a webview and then have a new view pop up  that has a navigation bar at the top (with a back button) and the content to be the link I clicked.

I currently have a tab bar template with 5 tabs and each tab is currently set to NavigationView and inside each of those tabs are views that contain a UIWebView. This is how I handle links:

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request   navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    NSURL *url = request.URL;
    NSString *urlString = url.absoluteString;
    NSRange page = [ urlString rangeOfString: @"/?page=" ];
    // URL is main page
    if ( [ urlString isEqualToString: @"http://somelink-yadayadayada.com/" ] ) {
        return YES;
    }
    // URL contains page number
    else if ( page.location != NSNotFound ) {
        return YES;
    }
    // URL is clicked link
    else {
        // THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO HAVE THE LINK OPEN THE NEW NAV VIEW.
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and If i need to provide more context I'll be happy to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question has been asked many times before. Please have a look at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790653/iphone-uiwebview-open-new-uiwebview-controller-from-a-hyperlink/3790678#3790678), it's almost exactly what you need, just change the `[BrowserViewController openBrowserWithUrl:url];` to whatever you need to push your new ViewController to the navigation stack. It might look like that:

```
LatestView *latestView = [[LatestView alloc] initWithNibName:@"LatestView" bundle:nil]; 

//Pass the URL here, depends on how you passed it into the WebView in the first place   

// Add the ViewController to the stack
[self.navigationController pushViewController:latestView animated:YES]; 
[latestView release];
```

Comment: Philibbo - Thank you for the info but I guess I'm not understanding the concept. I'm in a navigation view that contains a view that contains a webview.  I want to click a link that opens a new view in the navigation stack.  How do I do this? Maybe I'm not grasping the conceptual process in which I should be doing this. :(

Comment: Do you, in general, know how to add a new view to the stack of the UINavigationController?

Comment: I guess not.  If it's not to much trouble do you mind explaining?

Comment: Allright. First, you are talking about a NavigationView and a WebView inside a View. To make it clear, the supposed structure would be: UINavigationController contains UIViewController contains the WebView, at least as far as I know. Then, the ViewController containing the WebView should be made the WebViews delegate. Now you can insert the code I given you in the first place. For the rest, I will edit the answer right now.

Comment: A tab bar controller that has 5 tabs, each of these tabs are set to a navigation controller. Each of the navigation controllers contains a view that contains a webView.

Comment: Please use the proper names of the classes. So you say, you have a UIView controlled by a UINavigationController? Are you sure? I'm not extremely familiar with that, but I thought a UINavigationController may only contain UIViewControllers.

Comment: With proper names: UITabBarController contains 5 UINavigationControllers. Each of these UINavCon's are linked to NIB files that contain a UIView which contains a UIWebView.

Comment: Sorry, I'm baffled. How exactly did you manage insert a UIView into a NavigationController? I'm almost certain, that we are not talking about the same thing.

Comment: Each NavigationController links to a NIB file that contains a UIView and a UIWebView.  Here is a picture for reference: http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/348/screenshot20100928at240.png

Comment: Interesting... Tell me, what of what class is the Files Owner of the LatestView?

Comment: The class that is assigned to LatestView's File owner is LatestView.m

Comment: Well, yes, and it's superclass?

Comment: In the LatestView.h, it says something like "LatestView : UI..."

Comment: @interface LatestView : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate> {

Comment: UIViewController and not UIView, that's what I implied 10 comments ago :) Anyway, that completes my answer, I guess. I'll just update it according to your classnames. What's more: You shouldn't call a Class "...View" when it's actually a ViewController, that would have saved us quite some time anyway.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH. That worked.  I'll take the advice about naming a class View (I was thinking of each tab as the specific thing you are currently "viewing")

Comment: Hi, I am facing exactly same problem. I tried this solution but it crashes my app. I have already spent 2 days looking for a solution but situation is still the same. Please help me....