# UIWebView and navigation controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller

How can I tell my `UIWebView` to open links in a new View , using a `UINavigationController` ?

I found this thread, but i m a little confused of where to implement that piece of code (i m new to objective-C/IPhone)

[Clicking a link in UIWebView pushes onto the NavigationView stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815167/clicking-a-link-in-uiwebview-pushes-onto-the-navigationview-stack)

my view just contains a simple `WebView` with a `UINavigationController` on top

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface ContactViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView1;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *webView1;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are steps assuming your view controller (that houses the webview) is already within a navigation controller.

Within the .h - ensure your view controller conforms to the webview delegate

```
UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
```

Within the .m - add the following code (or just implement this method with whatever logic you want)

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
    YourNextViewController *ynvc = [[[YourNextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourNextViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    ynvc.ivar1 = value1;
    ynvc.ivar2 = value2;

    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
    [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:backButton];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ynvc animated:YES];

    return NO;
}
return YES;}
```

Comment: no problem - if that solves the problem and everything is working don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: I am facing the same problem but this is not working with me :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to objective C / iPhone too, but what I would try,..

Is creating a new viewController for your webview and push it in your UINavigator

```
yourWebViewController *y =  [[yourWebViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:y animated:YES];
[y release];
```