# Opening a new UIViewController when a link on a UIWebView is clicked

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

I found this thread which matches my problem: [Clicking a link in UIWebView pushes onto the NavigationView stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815167/clicking-a-link-in-uiwebview-pushes-onto-the-navigationview-stack)

However, the following situations are different:
Instead of using a navigationController, I am using a View Based application to manually switch to different viewcontroller when corresponding buttons are pressed.
Rather than using links I am using onClick method to detect when a user clicks on something on a UIWebView and trying to open a new ViewController with a new UIWebView.

Will the same code work or do i have to make some changes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will have to do some modifications

1st:
when `onClick`, you will have to redirect your current page to a new location
This location for example will be `MYLocation://GoThere`

2nd:
Update the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest`

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

NSURL *url = request.URL;
NSString *urlString = url.absoluteString;

//Check if special link
if ( [ urlString isEqualToString: @"MYLocation://GoThere" ] ) {
    //Here present the new view controller
    MyViewController *controller = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES];

    return NO;
}

    return YES;

}
```

Comment: Yesss. This is the standard way of doing it. +1.

Comment: ok.. this is working. However I have implemented this method in the webView delegate. I cant use self so i am am calling the main ViewController inplace of self. This is causing the app to crash. Can you please help me?

Comment: Then pass some date in the delegate to the mainviewcontroller that you are using, and copy this code to it MyViewController *controller = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES]; let the mainviewcontroller deal with initializing and passing data to the view it will present

Comment: sorry Omar to bother you again. here's what I did:
I called a function from delegate to pass control to the main view controller. There i tried to change view controllers using presentModalViewController. when that didnt work i tried using insertSubview. However none of them are working.
It seems everytime i try to add a new view controller viewDidLoad is being called. And when i tried to switch views from there that didnt work either

DO you know whats going on?

Comment: Hi, I am facing exactly same problem. I have already spent 2 days looking for a solution but situation is still the same. Please help me....

Answer (score 1):

I think you may use the shouldStartLoadWithRequest as Omar posted.
If the new viewcontroller has a webviewcontroller, then you should pass the url (or even the request) to the new viewcontroller to show the clicked URL.