# How to open mp3 links I have in UIWebView, in new UIViewController?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, swift2

My question is how to open mp3 links I have in my UIWebView in new tap/viewController? or how to fix the problem I have( the mp3 player is not fit the screen ).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening a new UIViewController when a link on a UIWebView is clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959456/opening-a-new-uiviewcontroller-when-a-link-on-a-uiwebview-is-clicked)

Comment: Reading Objective-C for a couple of lines should be rather easy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like below , use your ViewController instead of settingsVC

[Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959456/opening-a-new-uiviewcontroller-when-a-link-on-a-uiwebview-is-clicked)

**Swift**

```
 func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
                    if navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked {
    if request.URL.absoluteString.containsString(".mp3") {
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("settingsVC") as! SettingsViewController
                        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        return false
                    }
    }           

                    return true
                }
```

Comment: i used this but nothing happen when i click on mp3 link

Comment: post some code how you presenting a view when link is cliked.How you setting webview delegate?

Comment: now I solved it by make webView as deleget and now how to know which link clicked

Comment: i have updated my answer when link is clicked you should have some unique identifier to differentialte an mp3 link or other , suppose mp3 links have .mp3 extension then above code will be working for you. You have to pass url string to destinationView so that you can play audio there

Comment: Some mp3 links may not ends with `.mp3` Hence not work on that.

Comment: @jack add extra check as per your extension then

Answer (score 1):

Use the WebView's delegate to intercept the request URL. You can check whether the URL contains ".mp3" for example and then load your own UIViewController instance.

Specifically intercept the method.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

Here's an example on what you might should do in ObjC.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

if([request.URL.absoluteString containsString:@".mp3"]){

    UIViewController *playViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:playViewController animated:YES];
    return NO;
}
else
    return YES; }
```

Comment: thank you, but can you explain more with code because i'm new in swift

Comment: I'm not familiar with Swift. I'm familiar with Objective C. Do you want an Objective C sample?

Comment: I've added a simple sample code to my answer above which you could base your approach on.

Comment: Some mp3 links may not ends with `.mp3` Hence not work on that.