# Push to ViewController inside html onclick

Tags: javascript, ios, swift4

I have an html file and there is a link on html file. I want to open another view controller once I click on that link shown in **`UIWebView`**. The code snippet is belwo -

```
<p class="img-note"><image class="img" src="hand.png" width="15"/> For a list,<input id = "304" type="button" onclick="referToPage();" value ="Click here" class="wrd2-note"> </p>
```

Android developer did the same like this -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function referToPage()
        {
        var refpageno = document.getElementById('304').id;
        Android.referToPage(refpageno);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: look into evaluateJavaScript https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript

Comment: you really should look into using WKWebView if possible. UIWebView is deprecated. If you're going to use UIWebView, check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10959456/opening-a-new-uiviewcontroller-when-a-link-on-a-uiwebview-is-clicked