# xamarin ios webview on link click push new view

Tags: ios, webview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I used webview to display a pdf which contain url links to images.  However, I want to intercept the link click to display a new view instead

my webview code

```
        webView = new UIWebView (View.Bounds);
        string fileName = "EMG.pdf"; // remember case-sensitive
        string localDocUrl = Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, fileName);
        webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(localDocUrl, false)));
        webView.ScalesPageToFit = true;
```

I looked up how to do it in [obj c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815167/clicking-a-link-in-uiwebview-pushes-onto-the-navigationview-stack?lq=1) but I can't seem to find the equivalent method in xamarin ios

Comment: I figured out how to implement this.

drop the following code into ViewDidLoad()

    webView.ShouldStartLoad = 
    delegate (UIWebView webViewParam, NSUrlRequest request, UIWebViewNavigationType navigationType) {
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked) {
    
     PerformSegue("pushChImage",this);
     return false;
    }
    return true;
   };

and it should perform a push segue to a new view

Comment: You can reply to your own question. It's usually done in answers, not comments. So you can mark the question as answered.

Comment: @starc, I tried this method, but its not firing for each link click, while loading webview for first time, its firing all events, If I click link in some other page inside webview is not detected