# how to open link of any website that is present in webView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, hyperlink

I am using pdf and in that there are some links,

now I want that when i press any link it should be redirect to that link.

Is it possible?

how?

P.S.> I am using webview and using a link and with the help of that link we can see pdf on webView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps

[Clicking a link in UIWebView pushes onto the NavigationView stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815167/clicking-a-link-in-uiwebview-pushes-onto-the-navigationview-stack)

[iPhone UIWebView - Open new UIWebView Controller from a hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790653/iphone-uiwebview-open-new-uiwebview-controller-from-a-hyperlink/3790678#3790678)